# how to call combobox selected item from another class in java?

Tags: java, swing, variables, jcombobox

```
final JComboBox departure = new JComboBox();
departure.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"city1", "city2", "city3"}));
departure.setBounds(413, 11, 147, 20);
int selectedIndex1=departure.getSelectedIndex();
contentPane.add(departure);
```

I am coding a bus reservation system for my homework, I use `JComboBox` to choose destination and departure city. I want to call selected item from another class. In this class the user will choose his seat.

How can I call selected item from another class? Please help me.. thanks.

Comment: Make your `JComboBox` a class member variable & add a method to return result of `getSelectedItem`.

Comment: can u explain more..how can i make JComboBox class member?like that,(public JComboBox departure)??

Answer (score 6):

You could make your `JComboBox` a class member variable & add a method to return result of `getSelectedItem`:

```
public class MyGuiApp {

    private JComboBox comboBox;

    // constructor, init method, etc.

    public String getSelectedItem() {
       return (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
    }
}
```